# C# DataReader in 'some cases' returns null while Sql server returns value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Summary:
C# SqlDataReader can return table in most cases but failed in only one unit test case. However, for same test, directly running the stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server 2016 returns table with value.

Detail:
The code input @measures is a DataTable type. In most cases, the code can return table with data or empty table correctly. However, when I set @measures to a DataTable with value 14 (14 is ID for one measure/fact and procedure should return one column of type int) , the datareader will return no row and not even the schema of the table. 
I tried other valid ID (measures) by which procedure returns other int column. They all work.

```
using (this._connection = new SqlConnection(this._connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = this._connection;
    command.CommandText = "rpt_procedure";
    command.CommandTimeout = this._config.ConfTimeOutSetting;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@measures", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = measures;
    command.Parameters.Add("@parameter2", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = parameter2;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Dates", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = Datetable;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gra", gra);
    this._connection.OpenWithRetry(this.RetryPolicy);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        this.NumRow = 0;
        DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        string[] colName = new string[colNum];
        int startPoint = 0;
        if (schemaTable == null)
            MessageBox.Show("cannot get schema of table");
        else
        {
            foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                if (startPoint >= colNum)
                    break;
                List<string> temp = new List<string>();
                //For each property of the field...
                colName[startPoint] = myField[schemaTable.Columns[0]].ToString();
                startPoint++;

            }
            arrayList.Add(colName);
        }
        if (!reader.HasRows)
            return arrayList;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            this.NumRow++;
            string[] r = new string[colNum];
            for (int i = 0; i < colNum; i++)
            {
                r[i] = reader[i].ToString();
            }
            arrayList.Add(r);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

SQL test code that returns value

```
declare @Measures tvpBigInt
insert into @Measures 
select 14 

declare @parameter2 tvpBigInt
insert into @parameter2 
select 22
union 
select 10

declare @Grain NVARCHAR(20) 
select @Grain = 'Daily'

declare @Dates tvpDate
insert into @Dates
select '2016-12-30','2017-02-06'

exec rpt_procedure
    @Measures =  @Measures
    @parameter2 =  @parameter2 
    ,@Gra = 'Daily'
    ,@Dates = @Dates
```

Action I took according to previous StackOverflow questions:

1. Tried dataadapter
2. Tried executenonquery cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Both did not work.

Comment: What else have you tried to troubleshoot this? Have you used **Sql Profiler** to see what is executed on the server and returned for both cases and compared those results? You should do that first. Also as you did not post the content of `rpt_procedure` you will not get an answer here, just pointers on what else you can do to figure it out. Its equivalent to asking a mechanic to diagnose a problem with your engine without letting them open the hood (*where the engine is*).

Comment: Why are your parameters declared 'Structured' instead of the actual type in the Database?

Comment: You can narrow this down to SQL vs c# rather quickly.  Create a table in SQL, and at the end of the stored procedure, insert the results into this table before you return the results to the c# app -- then check if when you run the c# app if the table is populated or not.

Comment: What is that ugly `.AddWithValue` doing in there? It *could* be causing the problem.

Comment: @jdweng Presumably the OP is passing a table-valued parameter.

Comment: The SQL stored procedure doesn't use table-value parameters.

Comment: @jdweng The example of calling the SP shows TVPs being used, and their use is noted in the "Details" paragraph of the question.